# Use both premitive and proxy authentication for a apache HttpClient 4.3.1

Tags: authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to connect a target host, which requires a username and password for primitive authentication from a proxy server that also have its own host, username and password.

**Updated**

**The use case is something like this**

My System connects with internet using proxy assume  proxy.mydomain.com
And my proxy uses authentication to connect and authenticatuion is done using username and password

Username : MyDomain\myusername
Password : Password

Ok now the API or service which I want to connect is using Preemptive authentication I have some code snippet form API Docs :

```
final HttpState state = client.getState();
final HttpClientParams params = client.getParams();
myCreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, userPassword);
System.out.println("Created credentials for " + myCreds.getUserName());
// Apply the credentials to the httpclient for preemptive authentication.
params.setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
state.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, myCreds);
```

I tried with all apche clients from 4.1 to 4.3 but no solution at all.
I can set one credential but not getting how can both set together to a HttpClient ?

Below is my Code :

```
  CloseableHttpResponse response;
  HttpHost myHost=new HttpHost("172.17.8.192", 443, "https");
  CredentialsProvider myServerCredsProvider;     

  if (userName.length() > 0 && userPassword.length() > 0)
    {
        myServerCredsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();  
        myServerCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, userPassword);

        logger.info("Username : "+userName+" Password : "+userPassword);

        myServerCredsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(myHost.getHostName(),myHost.getPort()),
            myServerCredentials);
                        logger.info("After Creds Provider");

        client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(myServerCredsProvider).build();

    }


    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.mycompany.com", 8080);

    UsernamePasswordCredentials poxyAuthDetails=new UsernamePasswordCredentials("MyDomain//username", "password");

    CredentialsProvider proxyProvider=new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    proxyProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxy.getHostName(),proxy.getPort()), poxyAuthDetails);

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(proxy)
            .build();

    HttpGet getServerDetailsUrl=new HttpGet(BaseURI+DominoServerAddress+API_BASE_URI);


    getServerDetailsUrl.setConfig(config);

    try {

        response=client.execute(getServerDetailsUrl);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            logger.info("----------------------------------------");
            logger.info(response.getStatusLine());

            if (entity != null) {
                logger.info("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        } finally {
            response.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        isAuthenticate=false;
        logger.info("Exception Occured "+ex.getMessage());

    }
```

I am getting exception while trying to execute :

HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required

Comment: Can you post a wire / context log of the session that exhibits the problem? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html

Comment: Additionally, if this is NTLM style authentication the user name should be domain\\user ... domain//user would not be equivalent to domain/user - might be something else to check as well - follow @oleg's suggestion as well there is a wealth of information to be gleaned from the conversation exchanged.

Comment: @oleg thanks if you can see the problem is i have created an object of credential provide for proxy but no where i used it because i have no idea where should and how i use it ?

Comment: @pyus13: in this case you might want to be a bit more specific with your questions. HttpClient APIs are documented here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html